# how deactivate scrolling in javascript bootstrap navs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In my code i'm using bootstrap (navs) like this in my html :

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}   


<div class="row" id="container_R_economics">
   <div class="span12">
      <div class="dropdown ">
         <select class=" btn-Action" id="groupe" >
            <option value="">Awaiting data...</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="span3" id="reportingContainer"></div>

   <div class="span7 offset1" id="dashboard">
      <div id="combochart"></div>
      <div id="control" style='height:50px'></div>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="tabbable" >
   <ul id="ul_tabs"  class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
   <div class="tab-content" id="graphTabsContent"></div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="container_R_physics">
<div class="span4 offset4" id="dashboard_div">
   <div id="chart_div" style='width: 600px; height: 300px;'></div>
   <div id="filter_div" style='width: 600px; height: 80px;'></div>
</div>
```

when i use bootstrap (navs) in my page web in (`<div class="row" id="container_R_economics">`) and (`<div class="row" id="container_R_physics">`) i have a scrolling, how i cant deactivate it?

Comment: `height:auto ` should do the trick for that corresponding css style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried setting the overflow to hidden:

```
.yourclass-name{
overflow:hidden;
}
```